# Grabbing hidden nodes in React Testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

I am trying to assert that a div containing a required checkbox adds the class "has-error" when submit is clicked before the element is filled out. Here is what the test output looks like before clicking:

```
`<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="sheet sheet-xl mb-4 sheet-fed-bordered"
    >
      <form>
        <div
          class="form-group"
        >
          <div
            class="row"
          >
            <div
              class="col-md-6 col-lg-6"
            >
              <input
                aria-describedby=""
                aria-invalid="false"
                aria-labelledby=""
                class="form-check-input"
                id="test"
                name="test"
                required=""
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
              />
              <label
                class="form-check-label"
                for="test"
              >
                Test
              </label>
              <div
                aria-live="polite"
                class="form-feedback-group"
                id="test-errors"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary fed-focus-outline"
          data-testid="form-wrapper-submit-btn"
          type="submit"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <hr />
        <pre>
          {
  "test": false
}
        </pre>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>`
```

What is the best way to get a hold of the third div with class="form-group" to later test that the class changes to "form-group has-errors"?

I have tried:
`screen.getByRole("div"),  screen.getByRole("div", {class: "form-group"}, screen.getByRole("div", {className: "form-group})`

And many other variations of the above and of findByRole, queryByRole, etc...

Answer (score 0):

`*ByRole('div',...)` won't work because `div` is an element type, not a [WAI-ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles).

If you can't assign an accessible name to the element, you may want to consider applying `data-testid`, which would allow you to retrieve it using `*ByTestId`.

```
<div class="form-group" data-testid="form-div">
```

Then in your test:

```
const divToTest = screen.getByTestId('form-div');
expect(divToTest).toHaveClass('has-error');
```

Please note that `data-testid` is a last resort.  Testing Library prefers that the document is queried in the way that the user would experience it.  Take a look at [About Queries in the official docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) for more insight.